# Disable caching (for theme develoment) doesn't work

Tags: caching

I'm quite desperate. I have disabled it in the admin backend (Administration -> Configuration -> Development -> "Page cache maximum age" = "<no caching>"). In `sites/default/services.yml` I have:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

I even tried to disable the *opcache* (wich makes not much sense, of course). The templates get translated (or rendered?) only once after I manually clear the cache.

I'm using Drupal 8.3.4, PHP 7.1 with php-fpm, postgresql and lighttpd on CentOS.

To always clear the cache – by clicking in the interface or `drush cr` –
feels like compiling a c++ application. And doing a `delete from cache_render; delete from cache_dynamic_page_cache; delete from cache_entity;` in the `psql` console feels 500 times faster but also isn't really convenient.

Comment: What are you working on that is cacheing? Things like the addition of new templates will always require a cache clear if I understand correctly. Also if you don't want to use drush cr. You can truncate all the tables in the db that start with cache_ if you have database access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the procedure in */sites/example.settings.local.php*:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Local development override configuration feature.
 *
 * To activate this feature, copy and rename it such that its path plus
 * filename is 'sites/default/settings.local.php'. Then, go to the bottom of
 * 'sites/default/settings.php' and uncomment the commented lines that mention
 * 'settings.local.php'.
 *
 * If you are using a site name in the path, such as 'sites/example.com', copy
 * this file to 'sites/example.com/settings.local.php', and uncomment the lines
 * at the bottom of 'sites/example.com/settings.php'.
 */
```

This will enable the service for a null cache backend in *development.services.yml*, which you then can assign to cache bins of your choice by uncommenting these lines:

```
# $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
# $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

Then you no longer need to truncate the cache tables.